# Not getting desired out put while using 'OR' operation in Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, string-comparison

My OS : Fedora release 13 (Goddard)

There is 5 directories under 'test'

```
[root@localhost lab]# ls test
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5
```

**Script1**

```
#!/bin/bash
#below line for listing all directories under '/home/arun/lab/test'
ls -Al --time-style=long-iso /home/arun/lab/test | grep '^d' | awk '{print $8}' | while read line
do
#Need to skip few directoirs
if [ "$line" == "dir1" -o "$line" == "dir2" ]; then
continue
fi
#will take some actions here..as of now just echo only
echo $line
done
```

**Script2**[Only Modification is changed == to != ]

```
#!/bin/bash
#below line for listing all directories under '/home/arun/lab/test'
ls -Al --time-style=long-iso /home/arun/lab/test | grep '^d' | awk '{print $8}' | while read line
do
#Need to skip few directoirs
if [ "$line" != "dir1" -o "$line" != "dir2" ]; then
continue
fi
#will take some actions here..as of now just echo only
echo $line
done
```

Script 1 giving expected o/p

```
[root@localhost lab]# ./test.sh 
dir3
dir4
dir5
```

**Issue is :**
For script 2 , I am expecting below o/p. But there is no o/p [blank] while running .. Please help me in this.

```
[root@localhost lab]# ./test.sh 
dir1
dir2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second script, you want `-a` ("and") instead of `-o` ("or"). Think the logic through: every possible string is not equal to at least one of the two, but you want to skip when it's not equal to *either* of them, which is to say when it's not equal to "dir1" *and* it's also not equal to "dir2".

Comment: What a big mistake, @Gordon Davisson, Thank You Very much for pointing it out . better to delete this Post? I feel very bad!!

Comment: In logic this is known as De Morgan's law; A /\ B <=> !A \/ !B